# signing dll and postsharp

Tags: c#, msbuild, hudson, postsharp

I’ve got a problem with postsharp on my hudson CI server.  Whenever I try to sign a dll with specific version an error occurs. (Hudson is using MSBuild from cmd to build this project , building it as x86) :

POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: Unhandled exception (2.0.8.1275, 32 bit, CLR 4.0, Release): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyLoadException: Error while loading the assembly " MyProject.general, **version=1.0.5378.169** , culture=neutral, publickeytoken=4c1c78190569e723": Cannot find an assembly named MyProject.General, **Version=1.0.5378.169**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4c1c78190569e723'. [C:\HudsonHome\jobs\test\workspace\WCF\MyProject\ MyProject.project.WCF.Service.csproj]

(Bold text is the current version)

Also all csproj files are altered, adding a before build action that will replace old version to actual.

`<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<FileUpdate Condition="'$(CCNetLabel)' != ''" Files="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" Regex="       (\d+)[.](\d+)[.](\d+)[.](\d+)" ReplacementText="$(CCNetLabel)" />
</Target>`

CCNetLabel is an environmental variable that Hudson changed every time before build.
I understand that post sharp is looking for a dll of current version but it doesn’t exist. And I’m not sure why, on my project old CI server everything works fine.
I would be grateful for any pointers on this matter

Comment: Have you checked the permissions/ACLs of your services against the directories that Postsharp needs access to?  Just a thought since it sounds like you have moved to a new server.  All things being equal that's at the top of my list.